# getActionBar() nullpointer with my class extends activity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar

I have a DrawbleActivity class that extends activity, getActionBar() give me nullpointerexception().

when I change extends for ActionBarActivity it works! but dont show ic_drawer I am trying to build a Navigation drawer.

I will have issues with theme or activity? the minsdkversion is 14 I use IDE eclipse luna.

```
public class DrawbleActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Filtro);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you have to extend ActionbarActivity

Comment: it works with ActionBaractivity but i want to keep extends activity.

Comment: extend your Class with `AppcompactActivity`, `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated now.

Comment: Its time to move on buddy... `Activity` is never used now a days. `ActionBarActivity` too got replaced with `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: what is deprecated? extends Activity?

Comment: `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated not `Activity` if you want to show Action Bar in your class/screen, you need to extend you class with `AppCompatActivity`. @Slinker

Answer (score 0):

It's about 'openOptionsMenu()' .. see this link :http://blog.perpetumdesign.com/2011/08/strange-case-of-dr-action-and-mr-bar.html; if you have this line in your manifest 
    `android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitle"`
jsut remove it and try again.

Answer (score -1):

you have to request having an Actionbar via below code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // request for action bar-----------------------------
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Make sure that requestFeature() called before setContentView(). 
And remove "android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitle"  if having in your code.

Answer (score -1):

I must extends to ActionBarActivity. Also, I have to change getActionBar() for getSupportActionBar()  .

```
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```